# Выходы из жизненного кризиса в литературе

Tags: литература

В продолжение вопроса "Должна ли литература учить?" предлагаю вспомнить, какие рецепты выхода из жизненного кризиса предлагают художественные произведения - летальный исход не считается. Хотелось бы чего-то поизящнее. Мне вспоминается только теория мышечной радости: герой уезжает в горы, работает там лыжным инструктором, его мышцы "радуются", а мысли упорядочиваются. Можете вспомнить что-то ещё?

Comment: @tat, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Вариантов выхода из жизненого кризиса литература предоставляет массу:

- ничего не делать ("Обломов"),
- философствовать ("Гамлет"),
- биться головой об стену ("Дон Кихот"),
- устроиться на завод ("Тридцатая любовь Марины"),
- разводить пчел ("Приключение Шерлока Холмса"),
- женится/выйти замуж ("Война и мир"),
- убить свою жену/мужа ("Отелло"/ "Леди Макбет"),
- принимать наркотики ("Generation П"),
- перестать принимать наркотики ("Морфий"),
- решить, что смертельно болен ("Вероника решает умереть"),
- сойти с ума ("Палата номер шесть"),
- перестать быть сумасшедшим ("Шахматная новелла"),
- уйти на войну ("Герой нашего времени"),
- вернуться с войны ("Тихий Дон").

Вариантов масса - выбор за вами.

Comment: Если обобщить, получается: терпеть; хаотично метаться (как муха между рамами); сменить обстановку (уехать в деревню, горы, на море и пр.); изменить семейный статус/влюбиться/родить ребенка; устроить себе крутой стресс по принципу "чем хуже, тем лучше". Не так уж много. И изящества маловато - в смысле оригинальности. В "Шахматной новелле" от хуже некуда к лучшему - так всегда легче. Это близко к варианту "ввести в дом козла", сначала сделать еще хуже, чтобы потом вернуться к тому, что было. Потому и спрашиваю, что тема выхода из кризиса очень редко удается литераторам.

Comment: Как и позитив в принципе. Проще убить героя.

Comment: @tat, ещё у Аристотеля отмечалось, что искусство должно показывать не разрешение проблемы, а крайнюю степень этой проблемы.

Answer (score 3):

Не хотелось бы, чтобы литературу воспринимали как сборники рецептов. Художественное произведение отражает мировоззрение автора, а оно в свою очередь связано  (особенно в литературе 19 века)с развитием общественных отношений. Найти некий универсальный рецепт выхода из жизненного тупика у вас не получится Какой бы назидательной ни казалась литература, это все же больше попытка писателя высказать свое, передать свой личный опыт, побудить нас, читателей, к размышлению, поиску собственных ответов на поставленные писателем вопросы. Лично я подхожу к преподаванию литературы именно с таких позиций. Мне важно совместно с учениками услышать голос автора, а уж соглашаться с ним или нет, это уже второе.
   Что касается выходов, то в "Войне и мире" не водится все к женитьбе/замужеству, как написано выше. Для девушек того времени не было иных вариантов. Вспомните Пьера и Андрея: находясь в кризисе, они пытались сначала разобраться в себе, найти себя на поприще служения обществу, помощи людям, они искали, где бы применить то, что дала им природа, семья, образование, воспитание... Им мало было кататься как сыр в масле (аристократия, сливки общества)и жить только для себя. Они хотели делать что-то полезное людям, обществу. В какой-то степени - это отражение поисков самого Толстого, а уж этот человек знал, что такое самовоспитание и поиски самого себя (почитайте его дневники - какие программы саморазвития он составлял и как их выполнял!)
   Это только один пример. По большому счету ни один настоящий писатель не будет давать готовых рецептов: он слишком уважает своего читателя (=**со-творца**: один написал, другой прочитал и разобрался, понял, расшифровал), чтобы давать ему подсказки, тем более каждый сам проживает свою жизнь. Книга может помочь разобраться в людях, в себе и показать, как искали выхода другие, оказавшись в непростой жизненной ситуации. Неслучайно М.Горький называл литературу "человековедением", а О.Бальзак "историей человеческого сердца". Заметьте, про рецепты ни слова.

Comment: Естественно описанное в моём ответе - крайнее упрощение. Хотя справедливости ради стоит отметить, что в "Войне и мире" действительно все основные персонажи разрешили свои противоречия или женившись, или умерев (причём это касается представителей обоего пола), в эпилоге правда показано, что появились новые противоречия.

Автор задаёт достаточно конкретный вопрос, и варианты ответа на него представлены. То что разрешать проблемы - это задача не литературы, а философии и политики, думаю автор вопроса и так знает.

Answer (score 2):

Кажется, в романе Германа Гессе "Степной волк" рекомендуется в таких случаях обращаться к продуктам мыслительной деятельности, не связанной с работой эмоционального интеллекта, - шуткам. Роман любопытный. *"Жить в мире, словно это не мир, уважать закон и все же стоять выше него, обладать «как бы не обладая», отказываться, словно это никакой не отказ*, – дальше можно было бы не цитировать, так как силой эмоционального воздействия обладают уже процитированные строки, но мысль не окончена, - *выполнить все эти излюбленные и часто формулируемые требования высшей житейской мудрости способен один лишь юмор".*

> И изящества маловато - в смысле оригинальности. Потому и спрашиваю, что тема выхода из кризиса очень редко удается литераторам.

А что, скажите на милость, этим литераторам вообще удается? Назовите мне хоть какое-нибудь разумное число сочинений, реализующих революционные идеи, — я охотно откажусь от своего убеждения в том, что литература не реализовала свой потенциал.

Как правило, гениальные литературные произведения либо поэтические, либо прозаические в сатирическом жанре. И гениальными они становятся благодаря совершенству исполнения, а вовсе не оригинальности идей.

Иногда рождаются монументальные творения вроде "Мастера и Маргариты"... Впрочем, ничего подобного этому роману я не знаю, поэтому лучше вспомним о тех романах, которые реализуют идеи, ранее не находившие эстетического выражения в литературе. Немногие произведения, что составляют эту категорию, от булгаковской рукописи отличаются тем, что попросту пренебрегают исполнением, от чего их художественная ценность ощутимо страдает.

Вне всяких сомнений, литературный труд — самый тяжкий. Видимо, коэффициент интеллекта у человека выше "количественной оценки" способности анализировать деятельность интеллекта эмоционального и описывать ее с помощью вербальных средств.

Нужно, наверное, вернуться к обозначенной проблеме.

> И изящества маловато - в смысле оригинальности.

[[@tat](/users/3588/tat)](/users/3588/tat), я не знаю, что для Вас оригинальность, — возьму на себя смелость предположить. Если описанные в литературе способы эскапизма кажутся Вам лишенными изощренности, то позвольте мне обратить Ваше внимание на то обстоятельство, что иначе быть не может. Пожалуй, ни один гений не справится с задачей показать нам такой путь преодоления мировоззренческого кризиса, какой мы сами не в состоянии были бы увидеть.

Освободиться от ощущения невыносимости бытия можно лишь отказавшись от адекватного восприятия реальности. Отказ можно осуществить в пользу трех альтернатив.

Первая описана в романе "Степной волк". Вторая использует негативное влияние инстинктов на способность формировать адекватную реакцию. Инстинктов у нас вроде не так уж и много. Основной инстинкт в полной мере оправдывает свое название и подавляет всякую способность мыслить. По силе угнетающего действия на мыслительные реакции ему не уступает инстинкт самосохранения, подавляющее влияние которого на личность в литературе продемонстрировал автор "Вероники", а в кинематографе... Недавно появилось сомнительной ценности произведение... Там вот тоже — главный герой весь фильм в петлю лез, а как только петля на него полезла, — жизненный кризис как рукой сняло!

Третья альтернатива — творческая деятельность. Думаю, значение всеисцеляющей силы искусства все могут оценить. Когда стала очевидной неизбежность полной утраты слуха, от суицида Бетховена удержала только музыка, радость творчества.

Как видите, исповедать пути выхода из мировоззренческого кризиса оказалось нетрудно. И гениального интеллекта не потребовалось. Чем же гениям нас удивлять, если представителям инертного большинства все ясно? Настоящий список способов эскапизма не является исчерпывающим, так как я рассматривала только крайнюю степень тяжести кризисного эмоционального состояния, однако новых категорий к триаде уже рассмотренных скромность моих психоаналитических способностей, я думаю, не добавляет.

Comment: Что такое "вербальный", извините? От существительного "Верба"? От глагола "Verb"? Или от чего-то, ещё более эпохального?

Comment: @русак, от латинского  verbalis, "словесный".

Comment: @Марк Из, спасибо Вам. Видимо, "вербальный" на русском языке звучит более весомо, чем "словесный". Вы - отзывчивый человек, в отличие от НУАР, к которой был обращён мой вопрос. Ещё раз спасибо Вам!

Comment: @русак, я дополнила ответ соображениями по существу, почитайте, — может, Вам еще что-нибудь не понравится.

Answer (score 2):

Мне понравились рассуждения Софии. Но она не затронула одну из самых ужасных коллизий - безнадёжность, бесцельность всей последующей жизни. Пожалуй, сложнее, чем духовный кризис Григория Мелехова, в литературе не описано ничего. Это кризис не только героя, но и автора! Это кризис самой жизни, её принятой схемы последующего развёртывания бытия. Социализм (в том виде, в каком от трактовался и практиковался у нас в стране) как форма бытия невозможен в принципе, потому что он основан на отрицании собственности, а значит, и экономики как науки об основах нормального существования человечества. Обычно ссылаются на "шведский" социализм и другие его разновидности, но там всюду в основе бытия общества - частная собственность, то единственное, что гарантирует сохранение и накопление собственности и благосостояния граждан (понимаю, что вступление слишком длинное). К чему я говорю? К тому, что сам автор понял бесперспективность социализма и потому привёл своего героя к такому страшному концу, подобного которому в литературе не было. Отдалённо по социальной значимости такой конфликт показан у А. С. Пушкина в "Медном всаднике" (дилемма: Маленький человек и Государь-реформатор). Но там - частный случай, а у Шолохова дилемма более значимая: государственная верхушка и народ... Итак, конфликты литературные - это, чаще всего, нечто надуманное, и воля автора - заинтересовать читателя в действенности, важности рассматриваемого конфликта. Конфликт в "Тихом Доне"- это производная самой жизни, и убеждать кого-либо в его важности, наверное, не след.

Comment: Вы про какое время говорите? Во времена, описанные в романе "Тихий Дон" частная собственность вполне себе сохранялась. И строили коммунизм, а не социализм. Все плюсы колхозов Шолохов описывает уже в "Поднятой целине". 

Кстати, по принципу коммунизма, от каждого по возможности, каждому по потребностям, строят свою экономику большинство семей. Никто не перестанет кормить своего ребёнка, покупать ему одежду и игрушки, только на том основании, что он ничего не зарабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

В художественной литературе «разочарованный» герой, как правило, обречен – в лучшем случае он уезжает в карете, как Чацкий. Задача же литературы заключается в показе  того, как он дошел до жизненного кризиса.

А вот это уже познавательно и поучительно, можно пофилософствовать. Думаю, что  человечество можно разделить на две категории – цивилизаторов и потребителей. Их задачи  различны: цивилизаторы  продвигают общество  вперед, а потребители пользуются новыми культурными достижениями, закрепляя их в  окружающей реальности.

Потребителям душевный кризис не грозит, они выбирают себе определенную тему жизни (природа, спорт, дети, путешествия и др.) и  движутся внутри этой темы по кругу.  Что касается цивилизаторов, то они погружаются в кризисное состояние регулярно.

Цивилизатору нужна цель в качестве путеводной звезды, а ее  нужно выбирать с умом.  Цель не должна быть недостижимой вовсе, но и не должна достигаться быстро, при этом желательно фиксировать свое продвижение в нужном направлении. Иногда цивилизатор не может выбрать цель (Онегин, Печорин), иногда  ему не хватает Силы (Обломов).

К примеру, целеустремленный герой  жаждет посвятить себя служению обществу, а общество в этом не нуждается (Чацкий). А Базаров выбрал себе цель неосуществимую, и его искусственная система мира  не выдержала столкновения с реальностью – конец известен.

Вот и думается, что  душевный кризис  разных литературных героев не стоит сводить к одним общим формулировкам, рисующим  счастливую жизнь целеустремленных и деятельных людей. Именно у них чаще всего и возникают проблемы.

Comment: Для обозначения "цивилизаторов" в вашем понимании используется термин "пассионарии", а "потребителей" - "субпассионарии". Теория пассионарности Л. Н. Гумилёва, как историческая весьма спорна, но как философская модель внимания безусловно заслуживает.

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите " Преступление и наказание". Хотя там и нет никаких рецептов.Но то что роман поучительный, думаю, это несомненно.

Comment: На каторгу не очень хочется. Что-нибудь поцивильнее не предложите?